# How to perform play and pause operation with Flutter-tts?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I can not perform Pause and play methods in my project while using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts).

is there an options to perform pause and play the audio in `flutter_tts` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs I can see

```dart
// iOS and Web only
await flutterTts.pause();
```

and from the codes I don't see a resume or play option I believe you have to use the same speak method and the engine will find if it has to resume or play based on the state. However there is a listener for continuing

```
flutterTts.setContinueHandler((msg) {
  setState(() {
    ttsState = TtsState.continued;
  });
});
```

Comment: what about android?

Comment: Theres no method available according to the docs

Comment: android is now supported